# Is .ExecuteNonQuery() required to add sql data to a DB in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am running the following code (part of it) to connect to `PHPmyadmin` DB

```
Private Sub sreg_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SqlConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString



        Try
            If SqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                SqlConnection.Open()
                MsgBox("Successfully connected to MySQL DB")
            Else
                SqlConnection.Close()
                MsgBox("Connection is Closed")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End Sub

Public Sub SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatment As String)
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

        With cmd
            .CommandText = SQLStatment
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Connection = SqlConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

        SqlConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("Succesfully Added!")
        SqlConnection.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

However the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is giving me huge headaches in terms of errors and problems. It uploads the data but, it can only do it once (one upload) before, it returns an error.

When I remove the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` no data gets uploaded? So I guess it is necessary.

Here is the code im uploading (part of it)

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO students(student_id, title, initial, surname,
 street, city, pcode, country ) VALUES ('" & strStudent & "', '" 
 & vtital & "', '" & vinital & "', '" & vsurname & "', '" & vstreet 
 & "', '" & vcity & "', '" & vpcode & "', '" & vcountry & "' )"

 SaveNames(sql)
```

Hope my question makes sense and that I can get the message across

Comment: In your students table is student_id primary key auto increment ? What is the error message you get?

Comment: ` it returns an error` WHAT ERROR?

Comment: @MilenPavlov yes student_id is primary key not auto increment

Comment: @walther im not getting any error messages it just kicks out of runtime and says InvalidOperationException was handled and then underlines .executenonquery()

Comment: datatype mismatch. do no pass the student_id with single quotations

Comment: Debug the software to see the error message, there's certainly some message that will popup on you. Furthermore, your code is susceptible to SQL injection, so you should look into that as well.

Comment: If you're `Close`ing and `Dispose`ing this `SqlConnection` object, it suggests to me that you ought to also be creating and `Open`ing it in the same method. It's odd to control one end of an object's lifetime and not the other.

Comment: Have you ever heard of parameterized queries?

Comment: why dont you use stored procedures instead of inline sql statements to make it more safe and organize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your approach to save this data that could lead to your problem.
The first problem is that code doesn't use a parameterized query. This is a security concern (Sql Injection) but also a simple logical problem. If you concatenate strings to build a sql query you have a problem with strings that contains characters with a special meaning for the database sql engine. What if one of your strings contains a single quote? It will be seen as the end of the string with the remainder of your text as invalid sql.

The second problem is the lacking of open/close/dispose of the MySqlConnection also in case of exceptions. This is resolved by using the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).

So I would rewrite your method as

```
Public SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatment As String, List(Of MySqlParameter) parameters) As Integer
    Using con = new MySqlConnection(... put here the connection string...)
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQLStatment, con)
         if parameters.Count > 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray())
         End If
         return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

And call it with code like this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO students(student_id, title, initial, surname," & _
      "street, city, pcode, country ) VALUES (@id,@title,@init,@sur," & _
      "@street,@city,@pcode,@country)"
Dim ps = New List(Of MySqlParameters)()
Dim p = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(strStudent)
ps.Add(p)
p = new MySqlParameter("@title", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = vtital
ps.Add(p)
.. and so on for the other parameters. 
.. respecting the actual datatype on the database table
.....
SaveNames(sql, ps)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ill give it a shot. 1 Question what does the ps represent in `SaveName(sql, ps)`

Comment: regarding open close dispose I do have it but did not add it to my code here, please see edit version of question

Comment: the ps is a list of MySqlParameters. It is necessary to pass it to your SaveNames because the sql command text contains placeholders for the actual values and these values are passed along with the list of parameters. I can't find an example with MySql but the numerous examples for Sql Server works in the same way, just a class name change.

Comment: About the open/close, that's better, but I still think that you shouldn't keep a global variable to store the connection. Just create it when needed, open, use and close/dispose in the same method. In this way there are less chances of resources leaks due to exception or other unseen problems. [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand( sqlstatement, conn)
conn.open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

And as I suggested you .. use parameterized